# Loading requestCode from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've encountered a problem, and I don't know, how to fix it:

I want to start an activity for a result in AndroidStudio, so previously I was using `startActivityForResult(intent,1);` and everything worked fine.

But as my project has grown bigger and bigger, it is hard to keep track of already used requestCodes, so I wanted to keep them all at one spot.

Because of this I tried this one:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, R.integer.request_code_for_something);
```

The xml-Tag looks like this:

```
<item name="request_code_for_something" type="integer"> 1 </item>
```

So far, so good. Everything is loaded properly, but when I reach that "startActivityForResult"-Statement, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.checkForValidRequestCode(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:79)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:717)
 at company_name.project_name.someClass.someFunction(someClass.java:565)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Am I missing something, or is this just straight up not possible?

EDIT: I know that I can't use values above 32.767, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.integer.request_code_for_something` wont return the integer use set in xml. Instead it gives you the integer specified in R class.

```
public static final int request_code_for_something=0x7f040003;
```

To get the resource value. Use getResource()

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.request_code_for_something)
```